# How to add words from a text file to a dictionary depending on the name?

Tags: python, file, list, dictionary

So I have a text file which has the script of Act 1 from a Romeo and Juliet play and I want to count how many times someone says a word.

Here is the text: http://pastebin.com/X0gaxAPK

There are 3 people speaking in the text: Gregory, Sampson, and Abraham.

Basically I want to make 3 different dictionaries (if that's the best way to do it?) for each of the three speakers. Populate the dictionaries with the words the people say respectively, and then count how many times they say each word in the entire script.

How would I go about doing this? I think I can figure out the word count but I am a bit confused on how to separate who says what and put it into 3 different dictionaries for each person.

My output should look something like this (this is not correct but an example):

```
Gregory - 
25: the
15: a
5: from
3: while
1: hello
etc
```

Where the number is the frequency of the word said in the file.

Right now I have code written that reads the text file, strips the punctuation, and compiles the text into a list. I also don't want to use any outside modules, I'd like to do it the old fashioned way to learn, thanks.

You don't have to post exact code, just explain what I need to do and hopefully I can figure it out. I'm using Python 3.

Comment: You may want to use a dictionary where the keys are the names, and the values are the dictionaries like you were describing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import collections
import string
c = collections.defaultdict(collections.Counter)
speaker = None

with open('/tmp/spam.txt') as f:
  for line in f:
    if not line.strip():
      # we're on an empty line, the last guy has finished blabbing
      speaker = None
      continue
    if line.count(' ') == 0 and line.strip().endswith(':'):
      # a new guy is talking now, you might want to refine this event
      speaker = line.strip()[:-1]
      continue
    c[speaker].update(x.strip(string.punctuation).lower() for x in line.split())
```

Example output:

```
In [1]: run /tmp/spam.py

In [2]: c.keys()
Out[2]: [None, 'Abraham', 'Gregory', 'Sampson']

In [3]: c['Gregory'].most_common(10)
Out[3]: 
[('the', 7),
 ('thou', 6),
 ('to', 6),
 ('of', 4),
 ('and', 4),
 ('art', 3),
 ('is', 3),
 ('it', 3),
 ('no', 3),
 ('i', 3)]
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't want to be stripping the punctuation right away. The colon preceded by a new line is telling you where one person's quote begins and ends. This will be important so you know which dictionary to append the words in the given quote to. You will probably need some kind of if-else which appends to a different dictionary depending on who is currently speaking.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a naive implementation:

```
from collections import defaultdict

import nltk

def is_dialogue(line):
    # Add more rules to check if the 
    # line is a dialogue or not
    if len(line) > 0 and line.find('[') == -1 and line.find(']') == -1:
        return True

def get_dialogues(filename, people_list):
    dialogues = defaultdict(list)
    people_list = map(lambda x: x+':', people_list)
    current_person = None
    with open(filename) as fin:
        for line in fin:
            current_line = line.strip().replace('\n','')
            if  current_line in people_list:
                current_person = current_line
            if (current_person is not None) and (current_line != current_person) and is_dialogue(current_line):
                dialogues[current_person].append(current_line)
    return dialogues

def get_word_counts(dialogues):
    word_counts = defaultdict(dict)
    for (person, dialogue_list) in dialogues.items():
        word_count = defaultdict(int)
        for dialogue in dialogue_list:
            for word in nltk.tokenize.word_tokenize(dialogue):
                word_count[word] += 1
        word_counts[person] = word_count
    return word_counts

if __name__ == '__main__':
    dialogues = get_dialogues('script.txt', ['Sampson', 'Gregory', 'Abraham'])
    word_counts = get_word_counts(dialogues)
    print word_counts
```